# How to split a numerical value "x" by dividing it by a "n" number[Interval] and put that "x" value to "n" rows?

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, split, time-series

I am trying to make an Excel transformation using one single formula.

Following image shows the kind of transformation I'm looking for.

If not with formula, is there any other way to do this?

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Any formula or something ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will transform your data to Column D as long as data set has a same pattern as I see in your picture.

If data set pattern isn't always the same, then please specify what you need.

```
    Sub Transformation()
    Dim LastRowIndex As Integer
    Dim Value As Long

    y = 1

    With ActiveSheet
    LastRowIndex = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With


    For i = 1 To LastRowIndex
    Value = Range("B" & i)


    For Z = 1 To 4
    If Range("C" & y) <> "" Then
    Range("D" & y) = Value / 4
    y = y + 1
    End If

    Next Z



    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: I'm new to VBA ,Can i know how to implement this in VBA for Excel? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a Developers tab in your Excel's ribbon?